# How to write a bash script alias with whitespace on macOS

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sh

UPDATE:

I made progress, but I'm still unsure what I'm not understanding.  I've reduced my script down to a single line, and I still run into the same issue.

Any insight on the following?
*NOTE: if I enter "/Users/Da.../Docker" or as it is below using a backspace for the whitespace, the result is the same.*

`for myvm in $(find /Users/David/Documents/Virtual\ Machines/Docker -name *.vmx); do echo -e "VM name:  $myvm"; done
VM name:  /Users/David/Documents/Virtual
VM name:  Machines/Docker/RHEL7-DockerHost-Node04.vmwarevm/RHEL7-DockerHost-Node04.vmx
...
VM name:  /Users/David/Documents/Virtual
VM name:  Machines/Docker/RHEL7-DockerHost.vmwarevm/RHEL7-DockerHost.vmx
VM name:  /Users/David/Documents/Virtual
VM name:  Machines/Docker/RHEL7-DockerHost-Node01.vmwarevm/RHEL7-DockerHost-Node01.vmx`

What am I missing?

## --------------------------

I've found similar questions, but the answers aren't working for me.

I'm writing a script that will allow me to start and stop multiple VMs within VMware Fusion without having to click each one using the `vmrun` command, found at `"/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun"`.

### Problem

When I try to alias `vmrun`:

```
alias myvmcli='/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun'
```

...I get the following error from bash:

> line 3: /Applications/VMware\: No such file or directory

### Discussion

It obviously is missing the whitespace, but I thought using the backspace character would indicate that whitespace should be used.

I've tried single quotes and double quotes in the alias line to no avail.

If I run `alias` from the command line, it works fine.

### Solution/Thoughts?

I'm sure that creating a link can solve my problem, but I really want to know why this isn't working.

Comment: The [Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) states "For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases."

Here is a shell function you could add to `.bashrc` instead of your alias. Once adding it, you should do `souce ~/.bashrc` to make it available on the command line
    `myvmcli() {
        "/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun" ;
    } `

Comment: @Inian:  I agree with the gist of what you say about aliases, but in this case a simple variable assignment is all that is required.

Comment: @cdarke: Sure thing, but I would never encourage using variables though for beginners, so that would not be a regular practice

Comment: @Inian: why not?  Bear in mind this is a script we are talking about.

Comment: The question isn't whether you *can* do it with an alias, but why you *can't* do it with a function. `mivmcli () { /Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun "$@"; }`.

Comment: That said, I can't actually reproduce the problem. The alias definition is correct.

Comment: Thank you @cdarke, @Inian and @chepner.  I was able to resolve the `vmrun` issue in my script by setting `myvmcli="/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun"` and then invoking it with `"$myvmcli"`.

Comment: My problems with whitespace seem to persist (my VMs are in a subdirectory with whitespace (`.../Virtual Machines/...`)

This works fine at the command line from the dir below where there is no whitespace: `for vms in $(find . -name *.vmx); do <abs_path>/vmrun stop $vms; done` everything works as expected.  

In the script with abs path (w/whitespace), vms gets double the values-- (before & after whitespace).

Thank you for your help! 

An example of why whitespace is bad.  :)

Comment: We would have to look at the code to see your current problem - add it to your question?  Make sure you double-quote any $variable values containing embedded whitespace, e.g. `"$vms"`.  (I have often wondered how much time and money the name "Program Files" has cost the IT industry)

Comment: Thank you @cdarke.  Something I was unaware of-- in my script, I had been setting the variable value within a `select` statement.  Apparently, bash has trouble with assignments with whitespace there.  When I pulled the variable to occur before the select statement begins, the assignment and operation of the select menu operate as expected.

My apologies, as I didn't recognize this as pertinent to my original query.

Thank you again cdarke, et al for the assistance!

Comment: @DSpencer: not just `bash`, all shells that I know of use whitespace as a token delimiter.

Comment: Thanks @cdarke.  I do realize this (whitespace is a delimeter used for parsing), but just ignored the fact that's what I was doing in my loop (thinking it wouldn't since I was asking it not to in my head if not my script).    I _thought_ I was actually doing this by using the backslash and quotes.  

Do you know of any way to force the for loop to ignore the whitespace as a delimeter?  

What do you think the best way to handle a path with whitespace in it, if you're wanting to use it as a parameter in a command (such as I am wanting to do with `vmrun`)?

Thanks again!

Comment: For a `for` loop you can fiddle with `IFS=` (Intra-Field Separator) but I don't recommend it unless you really know what you are doing because of unexpected side-effects.  It's best to always quote values (as you have to in many languages) - there really is no magic way around it.  I used to teach `bash` and could break most student's scripts by just having a file called `'this is a file'`.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and knowledge @cdarke!

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid both functions and aliases by adding the directory to your path:

```
PATH="/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library:$PATH"
```

Then `vmrun` by itself will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote twice:

`alias myvmcli='"/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun"'`

or escape:

`alias myvmcli=\''/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun'\'`

or

`alias myvmcli="\"/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun\""`

Be careful of the way the 2nd and 3rd are escaped. They differ.

---

You need the double quotation because you need to quote once because the alias command requires it (`alias asd="echo asd"`), and then once again because the command inside the alias requires it.

---

**EDIT:**

Even though I answered this, the alias you posted, works with me just fine. Could be due to differences in bash version though:

```
[  0][s: ~ ]$ cd /tmp
[  0][s: tmp ]$ alias asd='asd\ zxc/test'
[  0][s: tmp ]$ asd
woooo!
```

Comment: What happens if you use the variable inside a select statement?  That's where it broke for me (using macOS 10.13 bash 3.2.57(1)-release).  The behavior changed when I pulled the assignment to before the select.  It still isn't working as expected, so I am looking at other options.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A backslash \ is not required inside quotes, it is retained. You would only need the backslash if you didn't use quotes, but generally quotes are good.

```
$ echo 'Hello\ world'
Hello\ world
$ echo "Hello\ world"
Hello\ world
$ echo Hello\ world
Hello world
$ echo "Hello world"
Hello world
```

Using an alias inside a script is not good, aliases are really designed as productivity aids on the command-line.

In this case just assign it to a variable, you don't need an alias or a function.

```
cmd='/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun'
```

Then, when you want to run it:

```
"$cmd"
```

Note the double quotes, required because of the embedded space.

Tested on OS X with vmware.

As others have said, something more complex than this would require a function.